# Does my HP 15t laptop have HDMI 2.0 port?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am trying to connect my laptop to my samsung tv with a HDMI cable. My TV supports 4k.  However, my laptop seems to display 4K @30HZ.  I read online that the reason the laptop does not display 4K @60HZ might be because of the HDMI ports or cable.

I wanted to know if my laptop does have a HDMI 2.0 port.
My laptop is HP Laptop 15-daxxx Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U, Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620.

Comment: Could you provide a valid model number 
so far i dont see any HP 15-daxxx.
Please check under your laptop and look up for a PRODUCT No.

Comment: The product number is: 5YQ23AV

Comment: I also wanted to let you know that  when I change the refresh rate to 60HZ,  the resolution changes to 640x480.  My point is that there is an option to change it to 60HZ but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Hi sorry for the long wait

> I wanted to know if my laptop does have a HDMI 2.0 port.

Short answer is **NO**

Your laptop HDMI port is only 1.4b wich goes up to 4096×2160 at 24 Hz
Here is the reference in the [Maintenance and Service Guide HP 15 Laptop PC](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06510442)

*Page 10 - Port section*

> I also wanted to let you know that when I change the refresh rate to 60HZ, the resolution changes to 640x480. My point is that there is an option to change it to 60HZ but it doesn't work

Thats because Windows is detecting the Intel UHD 620 (which is capable to send that resolution) but if the port is a HDMI 1.4b it is not going to display it correctly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way for me to get me laptop to output 4k @60HZ. Are there any adapters or something? 
I mean if Intel UHD 620 is capable of that resolution then why would they make a hdmi 1.4 port on it?

Comment: You could try and use the USB 3.1 Gen 1 Type-C port of your laptop and use a Type C to HDMI adapter, but im not 100% sure that is going to work at that resolution. i coudnt find a reference to let you know if that really really works.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: Go to Hp support site.  https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-da1000-laptop-pc/23301551/model/23301552?sku=5YQ23AV

Comment: It's on the manuals section

Comment: Yeah I found it, it turns out it doesn't even have a USB type c port.

Comment: Sorry to read thar, I mentioned that port because was listed on the manual.